# Material-UI Datepicker Year not displaying in the list before 2013

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When selecting a year it starts from 2013.I can't able to go to 1990 in that list as it is blocked in 2013 only but if I select 1 Jan 2013 and click on left navigation button it will take me to 2012.

So can anyone please tell me how to configure the datepicker so that it will show all the years from 1900 in the year list.

Comment: Have you tried using the minDate attribute to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by giving maxDate={new Date()} attribute in Datepicker component.
e.g

```
<DatePicker
    floatingLabelText="Select Year"
    maxDate={new Date()}
    mode="landscape"
    autoOk={true} />
```

This will not let you select future date but can show any previous date.